# Assign weights to links and different communities

Tags: netlogo

I generated a preferential-attachment with the nw: extension. Now I would like to assign different weights to links. My idea is to assign the weight 2 to a link between turtles **within** one nw:louvain-communities. Outgoing links to other communities should have only the weight 1 assigned.

```
links-own [weight]
turtles-own [ community ]

----

 nw:set-context turtles links
 ask turtles [
  ask my-links [ if member? other-end nw:louvain-communities [ set weight 1 ]
      ask other links [set weight 2]
    ] 
  ]
```

With this all links get the weight of 2, unfortunately.

---

So I copied this code to color the communities and edited for my purpose. It works how I want it but it is very confusing, and janky There has to be a better way

```
to weight-clusters [ clusters ]
  ask links [ set weight 1 ]
  let n length clusters
  let colors ifelse-value (n <= 12)
  [ n-of n remove gray remove white base-colors ] 
  [ n-values n [ approximate-hsb (random 255) (255) (100 + random 100) ] ]
    (foreach clusters colors [ [cluster cluster-color] ->
      ask cluster [ 
        ask my-links [ if member? other-end cluster [ set weight 2 ] ]
       
      ]
    ])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

when you run

```
ask my-links [ if member? other-end nw:louvain-communities [ set weight 1 ]
  ask other links [set weight 2]
]
```

you probably thínk you're asking the links that go from turtle A to louvain communities to set their weight to 1 and the links the go from turtle A to non-louvain communities to set their weight to 2. But if you look closely at your code, that's not the case.

when you call `other` after calling `my-links`, you're calling EVERY link that is NOT connected to turtle A. You say "With this all links get the weight of 2, unfortunately." but I expect it's closer to 99.9%: the very last turtle you call (turtle Z) will probably set a few links to 1, and every other link to 2.

the way to solve this is to be more specific about which links you call. The easiest fix is to stop using `other`.